# windows phone 8 current network strenght in db for cellular and wifi

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to get the network strength for both cellular and wifi in dBm for windows phone 8 devices?

I have searched considerably everywhere but unable to find anything related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, is not possible to do this with the current API.

Regards.